# Groovy MailService getting source code of sent email

Tags: email, groovy

I am using Groovy mailService for sending emails. 
For logging purpose I want to get the plain text of the email sended (like you can see in an email programm).

Code:

```
mailService.sendMail {
                async true
                to mTo
                subject mSubject
                from mFrom
                html outFile.getText()
            }
```

Is it possible to get the generated mail?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution:

```
MimeMailMessage mailret = mailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                async true
                to mTo
                subject mSubject
                from mFrom
                html mBody
                attachBytes filename, filetype, outFile.getBytes()

            }
mailret.mimeMessage.writeTo(System.out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate what the service internally does by (do this in a service or somewhere available for Spring processing):

```
MailMessageBuilderFactory mailMessageBuilderFactory
GrailsApplication grailsApplication

...
def getMessage () {
Closure callable = {
            async true
            to mTo
            subject mSubject
            from mFrom
            html outFile.getText()
        }
MailMessageBuilder messageBuilder = mailMessageBuilderFactory.createBuilder(grailsApplication.config.grails.mail)
callable.delegate = messageBuilder
callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
callable.call(messageBuilder)
println messageBuilder.message // (your 'MailMessage' message printed out here)
}
```

For more see http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/MailMessage.html

Comment: Other way of doing it would be intercepting the `MailMessageBuilder`'s method `sendMessage`. Let me know if you want me to elaborate more on this.

Comment: Thanks, do you think it's somehow possible with the return value?  MimeMailMessage mailret = mailService.sendMail

Comment: That should do the same thing. So yes, you can just the return value and access its properties.